# Windows 7 blue buttons in Swing

Tags: java, swing, button, windows-7, look-and-feel

In the force shutdown dialog from Windows 7 you can see two blue buttons which appear to be available to be available as a skin in the system look and feel. Is it possible to make a JButton look like these?

[image]

I'm aware that Swing simulates the system look and feel by checking the OS and that might be some custom skin that has not been implemented; and I've been reading the implementation of [WindowsButtonUI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsButtonUI.java) but I haven't found where that would be implemented (I believe it probably won't exist). I'm thinking on something if it could be enabled by setting a client property on the component, like any other look and feels do.

Comment: Swing doesn't rely on Windows; it merely checks that you are running on Windows, but then reimplements everything itself(!)

Comment: You're right, I messed up. Edited. I remember reading about the great work the had to do to mimic Windows and OSX LAFs. But anyway I believe that at some point it might rely on some system call since you can't use the native LAFs in other systems (including it in the JVM).

Comment: Actually, I have proven that to be false, Robin Green. If you get a Windows XP with a custom skin and you modify it, your Swing applications will change accordingly. Actually this makes sense, as reading further in the code I found that `sun.awt.windows.ThemeReader` has many native methods that do the system calls for painting different components.